# How to send an appointment recurrence without using Outlook with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

- What I have done here is to send an email with the recurrence and
  this has been added automatically to the receiver's Outlook calendar
  and this worked quite well.
- On the other hand, **my server doesn't have Outlook** so I would like
  to do send an appointment recurrence without using Outlook.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lbError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btSent" runat="server" OnClick="btSent_Click" Text="Sent" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lbRecur" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**C#:**

```
    protected void btSent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMail("huydq@abc.com", "ITD");
    }

    public void SendMail(string targetMail, string shownTargetName)
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("huydq@abc.com", "MailSendingProgram");
        MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(targetMail, shownTargetName);
        String fromPassword = "mypassword";
        String subject = "Test Recurrence";
        String body =
              @"
                    Here you can put in any text that will appear in the body
                    multilined and even in <html>
                ";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "RSC-MAIL2K7.abc.com",
            Port = 25,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };

        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        }
              )
        {
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
                lbError.Text = "E-Mail sent!";
                Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();
                CreateNewRecurringAppointment(olApp);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(olApp);
            }
            catch
            {
                lbError.Text = "Sending failed, check your internet connection!";
            }
        }
    }

    public void CreateNewRecurringAppointment(Outlook._Application OutlookApp)
    {
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appItem = null;
        Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern = null;
        try
        {
            appItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
               as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            // create a recurrence
            pattern = appItem.GetRecurrencePattern();
            pattern.RecurrenceType = Outlook.OlRecurrenceType.olRecursWeekly;
            pattern.StartTime = DateTime.Parse("8:35:00 AM");
            pattern.EndTime = DateTime.Parse("9:35:00 PM");
            // we can specify the duration instead of using the EndTime property
            pattern.Duration = 60;
            pattern.PatternStartDate = DateTime.Parse("07/23/2014");
            pattern.PatternEndDate = DateTime.Parse("07/31/2014");
            appItem.Subject = "Meeting with the Boss";
            appItem.Body = "Test Appointment body";
            appItem.Location = "P1";
            appItem.ReminderSet = true;
            appItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;
            appItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
            appItem.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
            appItem.Save();
            appItem.Send();
            //appItem.Display(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbRecur.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pattern != null)
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pattern);
            }
            if (appItem != null)
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the question here?

Comment: you may create an [ICalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) file manually and send it as attachment named invite.ics via an email, that should do the trick

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: My question is that "I would like to do send an appointment recurrence without using Outlook".

Comment: @pushpraj: As I thought It could be a great solution now.

Comment: @PMay1903 I have used a similar approach to push appointments to my gmail. however I did not used to set the recurrence, it was simple start/end date and time.

Comment: @pushpraj: Do you have any example for that approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample of recurring iCalendar (invite.ics) file

note that `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20150223T023000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO;WKST=MO` defines the recurrence. more on [RRULE](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
  METHOD:REQUEST
  BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
    TZID:Singapore Standard Time
    BEGIN:STANDARD
      DTSTART:16010101T000000
      TZOFFSETFROM:+0800
      TZOFFSETTO:+0800
    END:STANDARD
    BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
      DTSTART:16010101T000000
      TZOFFSETFROM:+0800
      TZOFFSETTO:+0800
    END:DAYLIGHT
  END:VTIMEZONE
  BEGIN:VEVENT
    ORGANIZER;CN= organizer's name :MAILTO: organizers email
    ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=recipient's name:MAILTO: email of recipient
    DESCRIPTION: event description
    RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20150223T023000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO;WKST=MO
    SUMMARY: event title
    DTSTART;TZID=Singapore Standard Time:20141215T103000
    DTEND;TZID=Singapore Standard Time:20141215T160000
    UID: some unique id if you wish to update the event later by sending another invite
    DTSTAMP:20140626T065810Z
    LOCATION: location of your evennt
    BEGIN:VALARM
      ACTION:DISPLAY
      DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
      TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
    END:VALARM
  END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

so you need to prepare a similar file with the recurring rule as desired and send it as an attachment named `invite.ics` to the recipient, and recipient's email client (outlook, gmail etc.) will create a calender entry accordingly

more on [iCalendar Specification](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/)

Comment: Thank you for your sample. As I've tried to send an attachment namely invite.ics to the recipient's email client who has Outlook. However, it showed an error as `The file cannot be previewed because there is no previewer installed for it.` and it didn't work.

Comment: it is due to incorrect mime type, set the following headers to the attachment `Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST`, that should make it recognized as a calender request